# LAMP webmail with PGP/GPG support?

Tags: security, ip, gpg, webmail, pgp

I've been asked to configure webmail for a company whose business is centred around their intellectual property - which is the rationale why we're using webmail, and not a client based email reader to access an internal only IMAP server. The other constaint is the requirement for PGP/GPG support, of which there seems to be a dearth of webmail systems that support it.

I do like the 'ooh shiny'ness of Roundcube (and the perhaps non-tech savvy end users would like it as well), however the patches for GPG support seem to be somewhat outdated. The natural choice seems to be Horde's [IMP](http://www.horde.org/apps/imp), however the code seems large, unwieldy, and perhaps no as secure as desired (due to their history of vulnerabilites).

Do you have a better suggestion of a secure webmail system which does have PGP support, or perhaps a more secure system design?

Answer (score 0):

Not as flashy as Roundcube but the well established [Squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org/) do have a [G/PGP plugin](http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=153)

Although the official version does not seem to be updated for a while, and contains security bugs. But according to that page and according to this [mail-list](http://old.nabble.com/G-PGP-Encryption-plugin-td32370868.html) there are version which work and with security patches applied.